# Powershell search a Listbox for a specific file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a search box for my `ListBox1` using a `Textbox` as a search box, i cant seem to figure out why it wont search the item i am typing in. please see below examples of how i want it to work and the code i am using.

```
$textbox2_Textchanged = {
Get-ChildItem $listbox1.items -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -match '$textbox2.text'} | Select Fullname
}
```

[image]

as you can see from the above it is filtering on what is in the `Textbox`
it needs to be able to pickup any part of the name like the below

[image]

to sample this working please copy and paste the below script into `Powershell IDE` make sure you change both `C:\YourDirectoryHere\` to your file path that you want to filter.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
$listsearch = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
[System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]$textBox1 = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$button1 = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.ListBox]$listBox1 = $null
function InitializeComponent
{
$textBox1 = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
$listBox1 = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ListBox)
$button1 = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button)
$listsearch.SuspendLayout()
#
#textBox1
#
$textBox1.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]86,[System.Int32]35))
$textBox1.Name = [System.String]'textBox1'
$textBox1.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]299,[System.Int32]20))
$textBox1.TabIndex = [System.Int32]0
$textBox1.add_TextChanged($textBox1_TextChanged)
#
#listBox1
#
$listBox1.FormattingEnabled = $true
$listBox1.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]77,[System.Int32]82))
$listBox1.Name = [System.String]'listBox1'
$listBox1.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]328,[System.Int32]290))
$listBox1.TabIndex = [System.Int32]1
$listBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged)
#
#button1
#
$button1.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]15,[System.Int32]18))
$button1.Name = [System.String]'button1'
$button1.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]52,[System.Int32]36))
$button1.TabIndex = [System.Int32]2
$button1.Text = [System.String]'button1'
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$button1.add_Click($button1_Click)
#
#listsearch
#
$listsearch.ClientSize = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]496,[System.Int32]411))
$listsearch.Controls.Add($button1)
$listsearch.Controls.Add($listBox1)
$listsearch.Controls.Add($textBox1)
$listsearch.Name = [System.String]'listsearch'
$listsearch.ResumeLayout($false)
$listsearch.PerformLayout()
Add-Member -InputObject $listsearch -Name textBox1 -Value $textBox1 -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $listsearch -Name button1 -Value $button1 -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $listsearch -Name listBox1 -Value $listBox1 -MemberType NoteProperty
}
. InitializeComponent

$button1_Click = {
$File1234 = GCI "C:\YourDirectoryHere\" -Filter *.pdf
 Foreach($File124 in $File1234){
 $ListBox1.Items.Add($File124) 
}
}

$listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged = {

}

$textBox1_TextChanged = {
$listbox1.Items.Clear()
$test = GCI "C:\YourDirectoryHere\" 
    if ($textbox1.Text)
    {       
        foreach ($i in $test)
        {
            if ($i -like "*$($textbox1.Text)*")
            {
                $listbox1.Items.add($i)
            }   
        }
}
}

$listsearch.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem $listbox1.Items.Text -Recurse .....`

Comment: @scepticalist thank you for the comment but unfortunately that didn't do it.

Comment: @Scepticalist i have updated my question with an answer. i have also added a sample script like you suggested

Comment: You answered a question (populate a listbox) different from the one you asked (search a listbox), but glad you worked it out

Comment: @Scepticalist the list box being populated wasn't the problem, it was using the `Textbox` to search all files in the `ListBox` i have added a gif to show what i meant

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. `. InitializeComponent` needs to happen **after** defining `$button1_Click`, otherwise, `$textBox1.add_TextChanged($textBox1_TextChanged)` is being added nothing.

```bash
$textBox1_TextChanged = {
    # defining this event goes before calling the function
}

. InitializeComponent
```

2. Not mandatory, but you probably want to include `-Name` to your calls to `Get-ChildItem`, else in PowerShell Core you would see the absolute paths instead of the file's `.Name`. Also, you probably want to check if the `ListBox` is already populated in your `.Click` event, otherwise it will populate it with duplicated values on each triggered event:

```bash
$button1_Click = {
    if($listbox1.Items.Count) {
        $listbox1.Items.Clear()
    }

    foreach($item in Get-ChildItem 'C:\YourDirectoryHere' -Filter *.pdf -Name) {
        $ListBox1.Items.Add($item)
    }
}
```